# On using a npm module in a Meteor package

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, bootstrap-tags-input, jquery-tags-input

If I install the npm module `bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa` in the main Meteor application I can use it by importing its files

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa/tagsinput.js';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa/tagsinput.css';
```

But if I use this npm  module inside a Meteor package with

```
Npm.depends({
  "bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa": "4.1.2"
});
```

I can not use

```
import '../.npm/package/node_modules/bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa/tagsinput.js';
import '../.npm/package/node_modules/bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa/tagsinput.css';
```

as the .npm directory contains a dot and is not compiled in the application

How can I use this npm module inside a package without the need to install it at application level ?

Comment: Did you try the paths  with `bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa/tagsinput.js` or `.npm/package/...` or `./.npm/package...`?

Comment: The problem is that ".npm" starts with a dot. Every directory starting with a dot is not compiled into the application source. So importing them fails.

Comment: That's odd and I am curious if this has been different in the past. Which Meteor version are you running on? And just to be sure, did you try just to import `bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa/tagsinput.js`?

Comment: Well well well, just importing with only the name of the file (without the full path) works.... silly me. (Meteor@1.8.1)
@Jankapunkt: add an answer and I will happily mark your answer as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well well well, just importing without the full path works.... silly me.

```
import 'bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa/tagsinput.js';
import 'bootstrap4-tagsinput-douglasanpa/tagsinput.css';
```

@Jankapunkt: add an answer and I will happily mark your answer as the solution